# Why is not using reflection in deserialization may lead to a remote code execution?

Tags: java, .net, reflection, deserialization, setter

I have read  (in "json attacks" talk in blackhat) that When using deserialize libraries, it may use reflection ("uses reflection to populate all fields or property members") or setters in order to construct the object. According to the talk, using reflection is not dangerous (and will not lead to remote code execution directly) as it does not invoke any methods.

It made me curious about one thing:

Why isn't using reflection dangerous? (as it construct an object too in the end. It looks the same like using setters to me)

Thank you

Comment: Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)

Answer (score 2):

There are fundamental problems with the statement in this form.

First, the phrase “use reflection” is meaningless, as it doesn’t tell *for what* reflection is used.

You can use reflection to create objects, use reflection to set fields, or use reflection to invoke methods. Only when being used for setting fields, it is safe to assume that it doesn’t invoke unknown code.

However, you are right in wondering why the construction of objects is ignored here. If the contents of an external file (like json) is allowed to drive the instantiation of arbitrary classes, executing their constructors is already dangerous. But it’s not unusual if the application tells the library which types to instantiate, not allowing other types.

But then, if we know beforehand which types can be instantiated, and those types are known to be safe and reliable, it’s not clear why we should distrust their setter methods. In fact, setter methods may validate the input and prevent illegal states whereas setting the field via reflection will bypass it and may create results that were otherwise impossible.

This doesn’t even have to be an intentional attack. A class may have evolved using a different internal state while still providing a backward compatible API, including setter methods. So, using reflection to set the fields directly can cause harm where using the dedicated setter methods would work flawlessly.

In short, external input must be validated, regardless of what you use to process it.

Answer (score 0):

Using reflection, while slower than setters, ensures that the only operation is changing the field. We cannot ensure this for setters because they can have code that is different to setting a value.

Comment: I see, so it depends on the setter of the object itself